# Windows Explorer defaultly showed attributes

Tags: windows, directory, windows-explorer

Which folder artibutes does the Windows Explorer hide?

Comment: I can't understand this question.. What kind of attributes are you talking about? Read/only, hidden, archive?

Comment: yes these kind of artibutes

Comment: and what do you mean about hiding them? As in attributes not seen when you right-click a folder and select properties? They're all there..

Comment: for example: its not showing the files with the `system` artibute..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Windows Explorer will hide files with the `hidden` attribute unless you select the option `Show hidden files, folders, and drives` under `Organize > Folder and search options > View`. It will hide files with the `system` attribute unless you uncheck the box `Hide protected operating system files (Recommended)` in the same dialog.

Comment: Thank you, that is all the artibutes that makes him hide a file\folder?

Comment: Yes. The other attributes don't affect display of a file or folder.

Answer (score 1):

Windows Explorer can show all attributes, it depends on what view you're in and what columns you have selected.

Add the "attributes" column to your current view, and it will show you all the attributes.

```
  R   Read-only file attribute.
  A   Archive file attribute.
  S   System file attribute.
  H   Hidden file attribute.
  I   Not content indexed file attribute.
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i know about the attributes coulmn and what each one mean, what i wish to know is what attributes make windows explorer not show the file/folder while in `Details` view